# Get browser width and hide element depending on size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, resolution

Is it possible to detect what width a browser window is and hide an element on page if its lower than 1024?

In JQuery perhaps? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  #someElement { display:none; }
}
```

Some older browsers don't support media queries, so you could use jQuery to accomplish this as well. This example will show/hide the element when the window resizes

```
<div id="someElement">SOME ELEMENT</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
      $('#someElement').toggle($(this).width() >= 1024);    
    }).trigger("resize");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    $('#someElement').hide();
}
```

or:

```
$('#someElement').toggle($(window).width() >= 1024);
```